# Iframe embedded youtube video won't replay in mobile device

Tags: mobile, youtube, frontend

I have a iframe embedded YouTube video in my web page.

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1&loop=1&rel=0"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

On desktop device everything works fine, on a mobile device however the video can not be replied. The first time its started it plays trough alright, but when it ends and I try to reply back screen only with the video title appears, no controls, no video, no sound.
Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Thanks